# PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeVideo returns no videos

Tags: ios, video, ios10, photos, ios8.1

**Edited** removed version from title, but this started with iOS 8.1

I have an app that I've built that will play videos from the users Photos.app.  When I install the application on an 8.0.2 device I get back a list of videos from the [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:options:] call no problem, but when I install the exact same code on an 8.1 device I get 0 videos returned.  Has anyone run into this?  Did 8.1 change the way we are supposed to access photos/videos from the Photos.app again?

```
PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
PHFetchResult *videos = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeVideo options:options];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

Modified my code to use PHAssetCollection call to try and fetch the album and I get some success, now on both versions I get 3 of my 6 videos (unfortunately not the same 3 each time).

```
PHFetchResult *collection = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumSyncedAlbum options:options];
PHFetchResult *videos = [PHAsset fetchKeyAssetsInAssetCollection:collection[0] options:nil];
```

**Edit #2**

Ok I just saw my mistake in the above code and I'm leaving it for anyone who does the same stupid thing I did.  My videos fetch line is calling for "Key" assets that's why I'm getting only 3.

```
PHFetchResult *collection = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumSyncedAlbum options:options];
PHFetchResult *videos = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection[0] options:nil];
```

Comment: It is working fine for me, With the code I get 40 videos, which is exactly the number of videos in Videos album of my Photos.app.

Comment: @gabbler Just for clarity I added the code I'm running, does that match what you are doing?  Also when you synced your videos did you do it by album from iPhoto?  Just trying to map all the variables.

Comment: Yes,it matches. I didn't upload my videos to iCloud.

Comment: please either edit the 8.1 out of the subject or piggyback ", 10.X" suffix to the subject: I want to get rid of my duplicate question for ios 10.x

Comment: the dup is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284967/phasset-fetchassetswithmediatypephassetmediatypevideo-returns-no-videos-on-ios

Comment: Removed iOS version from title, added iOS10 to tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self answering so if anyone else runs into this they might have an answer.

So I'm still not sure why my original code didn't work after upgrading to 8.1, but my code in Edit #2 solved the problem by coming at it in another direction.

```
PHFetchResult *collection = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumSyncedAlbum options:options];
PHFetchResult *videos = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection[0] options:nil];
```

Comment: 0 assets come from Videos. Would appreciate if you can check on ios 10.2. they are no longer hosted in Photos app

Answer (score 0):

Apparently both

```
PHFetchResult *videos = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeVideo options:options];
```

and

```
PHFetchResult *collection = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumSyncedAlbum options:options];
PHFetchResult *videos = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection[0] options:nil];
```

work in 10.1 but only IF the video is sitting in the Photos app.
The home (and other types of) videos in the Videos app
are not iterable.

So you can't use itunes of late to get a video onto device, you have to use AirDrop for the video to end up in Photos rather than Videos app.